# Get MP3 info from remote file

Tags: iphone, mp3, audio-streaming

I was playing around with the iPhone SDK and I wanted to get mp3 info from a remote file:

```
NSString *filepath = @"http://www.server.com/legal.mp3";
CFURLRef audioFileURL = CFURLCreateWithString(NULL, (CFStringRef) filepath, NULL);

AudioFileID audioFile;
if (noErr != AudioFileOpenURL(audioFileURL, fsRdPerm, 0, nil)) {
NSLog(@"Error - : could not open audio file. Path given was: %@", audioFileURL);
}
```

Why doesn't this work? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (-1) Define "doesn't work". Do you get the proper CFURLRef? Do you get an error returned and if so what error? Details, always details

Comment: AudioFileOpenURL() doesn't work with remote file, but only local file. However, how I can get mp3 (id3) info from a remote file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with remote mp3 file... :(